# How to manipulate the pattern of a RegExp dynamically?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of text `lines` and an array of `terms` with each `term` row containing a pair of words.  For example, the `terms` array could be something like:

```
blue, red
high, low
free, bound
 ...
```

for each line in the array of `lines`, I need to go through the list of all `terms` and replace every occurrence of the first word with the second word; globally and case-insensitive. For example, the line

`The sky is Blue and High, very blue and high, yet Free`

would become

`The sky is red and low, very red and low, yet bound`

A code like this:

```
function filter(lines,terms){
    for (line of lines){
        for (term of terms){
             tofind    = term[0]; //this is a string not RegExp
                                  //still needs the 'gi' flags
             toreplace = term[1];
             line      = line.replace(tofind,toreplace);
        }

    }
}
```

This is wrong, because `tofind` needs to be RegExp (pattern, 'gi') and needs to be generated dynamically with each iteration inside the loop.

If the `tofind` string was static, we could have done:

```
line = line.replace(/some-static-text-here/gi,toreplace)
```

I tried `line.replace(new RegExp(tofind,'gi'),toreplace)` but this throws an error `Invalid regular expression: /*Contains/: Nothing to repeat`

SO, the question is: How to modify the pattern of the RegExp object dynamically, inside a loop?

Comment: It appears that `tofind` starts with a `*`, and that makes it an invalid regex (because `*` is a quantifier, and there is nothing before it that it can be applied to). Other than that, there shouldn't be a problem generating `new RegExp`es.

Comment: What was the value of `tofind` when you tried `line.replace(new RegExp(tofind,'gi'),toreplace)`?

Comment: The `RegExp()` constructor is the answer to your question, but it begs the subsequent question: how to "scrub" a  plain string to make it a valid regular expression. That's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could build new regular expression if the terms array does only contains alpha numerical values.

```js
function filter(lines, terms) {
    return lines.map(s => 
        terms.reduce((r, t) => r.replace(new RegExp(t[0], 'gi'), t[1]), s));
}

console.log(filter(['The sky is Blue and High, very blue and high, yet Free'], [['blue', 'red'], ['high', 'low'], ['free', 'bound']]));
```